# Story about microscopic race that creates a minature woman probe

Tags: story-identification

I remember reading a short story years ago about a microscopic race that was in decline, with a serious need for new genetic material to save them. They made a last ditch effort to contruct a minature woman "probe" to possibly go get some.

This minature woman appears in a guys apartment, and although she is only a few inches tall, they somehow manage to have sex. His ejaculation is transported back to the microscopic race as new genetic material to save them.

I'm pretty sure it was in an anthology paperback of various authors, and I would have read it sometime around 1998, so it would have been written/published prior to that. American publication, written in English.

Comment: How many years ago? Do you remember where you read the short story (i.e. anthology by same authour, anthology with common theme, magazine, etc)? And what country and language?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it was in an anthology paperback of various authors, and I would have read it sometime around 1998, so it would have been written/published prior to that. American publication, written in English.

Answer (score 5):

Pier Anthony's story "The Bridge".

From a [book about the author](https://books.google.com/books?id=wcomJEpp08oC&pg=PA81&dq=the+bridge+anthony+story&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiwtMbOrIraAhVNHqwKHQjGCG4Q6AEINDAC#v=onepage&q=the%20bridge%20anthony%20story&f=false):

> In "The Bridge", there is an insterstellar transfer of energy, much like that comtemplated by the Andromdedans in the Cluster novels, except that in this case, the Oomians successfully transfer human semen through the angecy of a six-inch female.

I remember it as "Minie's Crew" (horrible pun, seems like him).  But that must have been in an author's note as an alternate title. Guess which stuck with me as a teen?

I would have read it in [Anthonology](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/15518.Anthonology?from_search=true), but [ISFDB](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?59389) shows it came from another anthology originally (with artwork).

Comment: Yep, I can't seem to find it online, but the descriptions I've found sound like that could indeed be it!

Comment: Which was apparently titled "The Bridge" when it was published in Anthology.

Comment: @Funderbunk You can read it at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Worlds_of_Tomorrow_v05n01_1970#page/n75/mode/2up).